# Does exist a way to integrate force.com with JMS (Java Message Service)?

Tags: force.com, integration, java

I'm looking information about Java Message Service and how to integrate this technology with Force.com using apex code. Does somebody has an idea of how to do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The only way to accomplish this is to expose the JMS as a public webservice. Then you can access it via standard apex callout methods.